# How to export dataframe to excel

Tags: r

I have been searching on how to do this. I know how to easily do this in MATLAB, but it is proving difficult in R. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: If the above link doesn't get you to a solution, please provide more detail about exactly what you are trying to accomplish. What file type you're trying to save as, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to write to specifically an .xls or .xlsx file or does any format work? Typically you might want to write to a CSV instead since it has been support.

Answer (score 3):

Writing to a .csv is often a way to go in R.
Alternatively, you can use the [xlsx package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html)

Installing the package

```
install.packages("xlsx")
```

Writing with the package

```
library(xlsx)

write.xlsx(YourDataFrame, "C:/Temp/YourExcelFile.xlsx")
```

Keep us posted! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `write.csv` command. Excel is able to read `csv` files.

`write.table(x = my_dataframe, file = "my_file.csv")`